# Can't use React tooltips in another Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I was trying to make a separated component for React Tooltips so I can use it again in my project,
But It seems to not work and gives me an error once the App reloads.
`The Error`
[image]

I Already install react-bootstrap and bootstrap using `npm i react-bootstrap bootstrap`
I'm using NextJs with ReactJs.

The Tooltip Component
`Tooltip.js`

```
import { OverlayTrigger, Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default function TitleTooltip({placement = 'top', title = ''}) {
    return (
        <OverlayTrigger
        placement={placement}
        overlay={
            <Tooltip id={`tooltip-${placement}`}>
                {title}
            </Tooltip>
        }
        >
        </OverlayTrigger>
    )
}
```

The Component I'm trying to use tooltips with
`Test.js`

```
import TitleTooltip from '../tooltips/Tooltip';
export default function Testing(){
return(
<div>
 <TitleTooltip placement='top' title={'This is some text'}>
  <p>Hover me</p>
 </TitleTooltip>
</div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the `<TitleTooltip>` component to receive the `children` (this is the element that you're wanting the tooltip to apply to, in your case `<p>Hover me</p>`) and render the child element within the `<OverlayComponent>` like this:

```
function TitleTooltip({ children, placement = "top", title = "" }) {
  return (
    <OverlayTrigger
      placement={placement}
      overlay={<Tooltip id={`tooltip-${placement}`}>{title}</Tooltip>}
    >
      {/* Render the child element */}
      {children}
    </OverlayTrigger>
  );
}
```

Here's a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-gates-1qthlv?file=/src/App.js) showing how you can re-use the `TitleTooltip` component.

Comment: Thanks, I understood now, I had to pass the child to the overLay Component, Which I wasn't so the Component was just hanging out by itself without the paragraph inside it lol